# aspose cells for java filter with contains option

Tags: java, aspose-cells

I am working on the autofilter option in aspose cells for java .

```
AutoFilter autoFilter = worksheet.getAutoFilter();
autoFilter.setRange("A1:D1");
autoFilter.filter(1, "Student");
```

This is working fine. But for the 3rd column I want to filter with "contains" option . 
In excel we can click on text filter and click on contains option, then we can filter with the text which contains some sub text.
For example if I want to filter all the text which contains "school" :
(result might be like aaa school, bbb school, xxx school etc)
How can I do that in aspose cells for java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following sample code for your reference:

AutoFilter autoFilter = worksheet.getAutoFilter();

autoFilter.setRange("A1:D1");

autoFilter.custom(1, FilterOperatorType.EQUAL, "*school*");

autoFilter.refresh();

........

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.